# Programming Zebra TLP 2824 Plus to print barcodes on side by side labels

Tags: javascript, html, printing, zpl

I have code that prints a series of labels with barcodes on them.

These barcodes correspond with a session number that the user inputs.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/BarCode.js") %>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv(divName) {
        var txt = $find("<%= txtSessionID.ClientID %>")
        var sessionID = txt._savedValidationValue;

        var cbo = $find("<%= cboNumOfLabels.ClientID %>")
    var item = cbo._value;

    JsBarcode("#barcode", sessionID);

    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;

        //start at index 1 bc printContents already contains 1 barcode, above
    for (var x = 1; x < item; x++)
        printContents += document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;

    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;

        //needed to allow new selection of cboNumOfLabels   
    location.reload(true);
}
</script>



<div class="sectionHeader">Print Barcode Labels</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div style="float: right">
        <div id="barcodeArea">
            <svg id="barcode"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divTable">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSessionID" runat="server" Text="Enter Session ID" CssClass="searchTable" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtSessionID" runat="server" CssClass="searchTable" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNumOfLabels" runat="server" Text="Number of Labels" CssClass="searchTable" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox clientID="cboClientID" ID="cboNumOfLabels" runat="server">
                        <Items>
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="1" Value="1" />
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="2" Value="2" />
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="3" Value="3" />
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="4" Value="4" />
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="5" Value="5" />
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="6" Value="6" />
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="7" Value="7" />
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="8" Value="8" />
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="9" Value="9" />
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="10" Value="10" />
                        </Items>
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="buttonArea">
        <input type="button" id="btnPrintBarcode" onclick="printDiv('barcodeArea')" value="Print Barcode" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The Zebra printer is currently printing labels that are 2.25" x 1.25".
[2.25" x 1.25" Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6svnq.jpg)

I'm trying to figure out how to configure this specific printer to print 1" x 1" labels with 2 on each sheet.
[1" x 1" labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgywc.jpg)

I've looked at all the settings in the Zebra Setup Utilities software but couldn't find anything that specified having two labels on each row.

I figured this would have to be solved with some programming so I went out and found this piece of code
that specifies the print width and fields to your needs.

```
^XA
^A0N20,20^FO50,100^FDText on left label^FS
^A0N20,20^FO250,100^FDText on right label^FS
^XZ
```

[Side by Side print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te639.jpg)

I'm not sure how to go about manipulating the code so that it prints the barcodes on each 1"x 1" label or if i'm even going about this the right way. PS. First time working with a label printer. I appreciate any and all help. Thank you.

Comment: You are on the right track.  Zebra printers only recognize label breaks across the label roll.  Side by side labels must be programmed as a single label.  Just break your label formatting into a function that takes a left-offset value, and call it twice, once with zero offset, then with ~half width offset.  Then wrap the returned ZPL in `^XA` and `^XZ` and any default values needed.

Comment: I tried what you said and it worked. Only problem now is getting the barcode to print as the label printer is currently in Generic/Text only mode to be able to process the ZPL code. Any ideas on this?

Comment: I suspect you have accidentally enabled communication diagnostics.  Looking at the manual for the 2824, you need to send `^default` to the printer.

Comment: Generic/Text only mode for printing barcodes is just fine. What type of barcode do you want to print?